# After compile of dll namespace is excluded

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am working with a web-service dll that has an integrator class to be used as a easy to use interface. after build this class and its namespace is not available in the dll!? The web-service interface that do the behind the scene functionality is still there, with namespaces and classes. it does not seem to matter if i move the integrator class around into other namespaces. it seems this class must not be compiled with the rest of the classes.

any takes on this?

Comment: Is the integrator class declared public ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is probably declared as private or internal.

Make sure you use the `public` keyword

```
public class Foo
```

and not

```
class Foo
```